# Jinja2 using {% include 'XXXXX' %} variables

Tags: django, jinja2

I'm not sure how to explain this. At work we didnt get any training on this and the supplier is a bit crap. We were told we are using Jinja2. We can create what we call a "block" in Jinja code using already existing variables. Once we created these blocks from Jinja2 code we can reference them with an `include` statement.

In my case this variable I created is a date. I want to create a new block using and formatting this variable. How could I use the below in another statement?

`{% include 'eme_sa_post_booking_personalisation_startdate_formatted' %}`

This will return 15/01/2022 for example

based on existing criteria I can use I want to format this date from the include statement by specific languages.

so lets say :

```
{%- if **-included variable-**  and contact.language in ('EN','FR','IE','SP','IT','FI') -%}

{{ **-include variable-**|format_date('dd/MM/yyyy') }}{#-EN,FR,IE,SP,IT,FI  have their date as 01.12.1900-#}

{%- elif **-included variable-** and contact.language == 'HG' -%}

{{ **-included variable-**|format_date('yyyy.MM.dd.') }}{#-HG have their date as 1900.12.01. -#}

{%- elif **-included variable-** and contact.language == 'SW' -%}

{{ **-included variable-**|format_date('dd.MM.yyyy') }}{#-SW have their date as 01.01.1900-#}

{%- elif **-included variable-** and contact.language == 'GR' -%}

{{ **-included variable-**|format_date('dd.MM.yyyy') }}{#-GR have their date as 01.01.1900-#}

{%- else -%}

{{ **-included variable-**|format_date('dd/MM/yyyy') }}{#-for all other languages we`ll use 01/12/1900-#}

{%- endif %}
```

Thanks

Comment: Wouldn't you just be able to call the variable? Like 
`{{ eme_sa_post_booking_personalisation_startdate_formatted |format_date('dd/MM/yyyy') }}`

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean here. the `include` tag be it jinja2 / Django literally _includes_ another template into the current one, it doesn't include a variable as what you say seems to suggest. Also if what your question asks is to format a date you don't even need to ask / speak about `include`. Also please tag your question correctly is it about Django Template Language or jinja2?

Comment: that doesn`t work unfortunately. I would have to either have something to call that include statement in my if statement or have it as xxxxx.eme_sa_post... otherwise it doesnt work:(

Comment: the new variable that I created using jinja 2 called "eme_sa_post...." has been created in the app we are using called "Simon data" in a place called "blocks". All I want to do is to reference this new variable in a new piece of jinja block to create a new block. By just using the name like "eme_sa_post..." I doesn't recognise it in my expression as I have to have something like contact.eme_sa_post...  the only way to have it I assumed would be to have an include statement which would then display my result but that's not enough as I need to have it formatted using other criteria